# Find out values which are not available in table

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

Let assume Following simple table

```
Col1
======
one
two
```

Let assume Following simple query

```
Select count(*) from TABLE_A where Col1 in ('one','two','three','four')
```

In above query it will produce following result

```
  2
```

Now I want to find out what are the values in IN- condition which is not available in table_A.

How to find out that values which are not available in table?

like below result

```
three
four
```

Above queries only example. In my real time query in have 1000 values in IN-Condition.

**Working Database : DB2**

Comment: If the 1000 values in `IN` condition then, you can add a table and store all the 1000 records in it. Then using `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check you can easily find the not-matching records

Comment: @Arulkumar . already I knew about that method . I need solution any other method.

Comment: Might a syntax-alternative for the specification of the VALUES() suffice as _any other_ method? When that IN-predicate is composed as [or effectively; I can not test the non-select subquery syntax] `Col1 in (values('one'),('two'),('three'),('four'))` then that same syntax could be used in an EXCEPT query [or the similar effect of EXCEPTION JOIN to the already proposed LEFT JOIN].

Comment: If the question is indeed specific to DB2 [note there a multiple; perhaps adding the tag for that specific variant has some value], then perhaps the tag for mysql should be removed?

Answer (score 3):

This is the one of the work around to achieve your expectation.

Instead of hard-coding the values in `IN` condition, you can move those values in to a table. If it done simply using `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check you can get the not matching values.

```
SELECT MR.Col1
FROM MatchingRecords MR -- here MatchingRecords table contains the IN condition values
LEFT JOIN Table_A TA ON TA.Col1 = MR.Col1
WHERE TA.Col1 IS NULL;
```

<kbd>[`Working DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f38ccc/3)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

If the values are to be listed in the statement string rather than stored in a table, then perhaps a revision to the syntax being used for that list of values currently being composed [apparently, from some other input than a TABLE] for the IN predicate can be effected?  The following revised syntax for a list of values could be used both for the original aggregate query [shown immediately below as the first of two queries], and for the query for which the how-to-code is being asked [the second of the two queries below]:

```
Select count(*)
from TABLE_A
where Col1 in ( values('one'),('two'),('three'),('four') )
; -- report from above query follows:
COUNT ( * )
          2
```

[Bgn-Edit 05-Aug-2016: adding this text and example just below]
Apparently at least one DB2 variant balks at unnamed columns for the derived table, so the query just below names the column; I chose COL1, so as to match the name from the actual TABLE, but that should not be necessary.  The `(col1)` is added to the original query that remains from the original pre-edit version; that version remains after this edit\insertion and is missing the `(col1)` added here:

```
select *
from   ( values('one'),('two'),('three'),('four') ) as x (col1)
except ( select * from table_a )
; -- report from above query follows:
COL1
three 
four
```

The following is the original query given, for which the comment below suggests a failure for an unnamed column when run on some unstated DB2 variant; I should have noted that this SQL query functions without error, on DB2 for i 7.1

[End-Edit 05-Aug-2016]

```
select *
from   ( values('one'),('two'),('three'),('four') ) as x
except ( select * from table_a )
; -- report from above query follows:
VALUES
three 
four
```

Comment: Your query is giving error like  "No column name was specified for column 1 of 'x'". @CRPence

Comment: What is shown functions without error on the IBM DB2 for i SQL with IBM i 7.1  Nevertheless, the syntax to name columns for a derived table is a parenthetical column-list following the AS-identifier.  I will edit the answer to include that